# proguard warning library class android.webkit.WebView depends on program class android.webkit.WebViewClien

Tags: android, proguard, webviewclient

I have a version of file android.webkit.WebViewClient in my application source directory in order to handle onReceivedSslError in my own extended version of WebViewClient. When I use the new ProGuard integration in sdk-7 I get the following warning:

```
[proguard] Warning: library class android.webkit.WebView depends on program class android.webkit.WebViewClient

...

 [proguard] Warning: there were 1 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
 [proguard]          You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
 [proguard]          be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this in my proguard.cfg? Thanks :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to put a library class in your source directory.  Can't you just extend the framework class directly?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working around the bug described here for OS's before Froyo http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blankempty-page/ Because there are some private apis, I can't simply extend the class :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, and by hint of above,
I write these lines into `proguard.cfg` and the problem gets solved:

```
-keep public class android.net.http.SslError
-keep public class android.webkit.WebViewClient

-dontwarn android.webkit.WebView
-dontwarn android.net.http.SslError
-dontwarn android.webkit.WebViewClient
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in your proguard.cfg or proguard-project.txt file:

```
-dontwarn android.webkit.WebView
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a bit late, but I had the same issue. I needed to support SSL connections in `WebView` on androids lower than 2.2.

I was able to build apk with proguard successfully by following:

- as said in comments - remove `android.webkit.WebViewClient` from your source, instead create your own class and extend original `WebViewClient` with only `onRecieveSslError` method inside (no overriding).
- replace existing `WebViewClient` usage with a new one
- `SslError` can be left unchanged, since on SDK 7 and lower it doesn't exists in open API, so proguard will not notice it.

That's it.